# Remove the OVERLAP of two arrays in snowflake

Tags: arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two arrays:

`brands_followed = {'gucci', 'prada'}`

`brands_unfollowed = {'prada'}`

I'm looking to keep only the elements in brands_followed that don't occur in brands_unfollowed - i.e. remove the intersection:

`final_brand_selection = {'gucci'}`

I see array_intersection() will tell me the elements in both. (But actually brands_unfollowed is a subset of brands followed so it's not useful.) How do I remove the unfollowed brands?

Comment: Please show some sample data (in proper json format) and expected result

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Javascript UDF for this:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_final(a array, b array)
   RETURNS array
   LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
   AS
   $$
      var c = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        if (B.includes(A[i]))
            continue
        else
            c.push(A[i])
      }
      return c
    $$;
```

Then a select:

```
select array_final(PARSE_JSON('["gucci","prada"]'), PARSE_JSON('["prada"]'));
```

would give me something like this:

[image]